# how can i split the data in a var and push to an array in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have tried the below code, to split the latitude and longitude values, but its more complex. Is there any easy ways. Below shown is my code. I have used many replace functions as well split functions...

```
var data  = [{"latitude":1.9,"longitude":103.57},{"latitude":1.338,"longitude":103.1},{"latitude":1.33,"longitude":103.7556}]
var re3 = /[\"\'\ ]+/g
data = data.replace(re3,'')
var re2 = /[\[\]\ ]+/g
data = data.replace(re2,'"')
var re1 = /[\'\r'\'\n'\{\ ]+/g
var data = data.replace(re1, '')
var re = /[\{\ ]+/g   
var data = data.replace(re, '')
var re4 = /},/g   
data = data.replace(re1, ';')
var re5 = /[\}\"\ ]+/g
data = data.replace(re, '')        
let value = data.split(';');
console.log(value)
let valueArr = [];
value.forEach(geo => {
if (geo) {
let l = geo.split(',');
valueArr.push({
latitude: latLong[0],
longitude: latLong[1],
});
}
});
```

I would like to get output like

latitude: 1.9,

longitude: 1

and so on in the arr

```
03.57
```

Comment: Is `data` supposed to be a string?

Comment: no, its like an array

Comment: Then why are you calling `data.replace`? That throws an error.

Comment: I am reading this data from a file as it is, I worked on above code, but its not throwing errors

Comment: but I am making the code more complex, so I asked if any easy way to split and push data like shown above

Comment: looks like an array but its a string itself I think, may be because of that I am not getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data seems to be in JSON format. Use `JSON.parse()`.

```js
var data = JSON.parse('[{"latitude":1.9,"longitude":103.57},{"latitude":1.338,"longitude":103.1},{"latitude":1.33,"longitude":103.7556}]');

console.log(data[0].latitude, data[0].longitude);
```